# How to set Text in the Column of the table in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to show text in table column regrading to comparison of amounts. This is my Access Query table

[image]

Now in new column (Status) I need to show

1) "NOT PAID" if AmountDue is equal to GrandTotal or

2) "PARTIALLY PAID" if AmountDue is less then GrandTotal  or

3) "PAID" if AmountDue is zero

My SQL Query code is

```
SELECT InvoiceNumber, 
Terms(Select PaymentTerms from PSD_customerPaymentTerms where PSD_customerPaymentTerms.PTId = NewInvoice_1.Terms) AS Terms, 
InvoiceDate, OurQuote, 
SalesPerson(Select FirstName from Employee where Employee.EmployeeId = NewInvoice_1.SalesPerson) AS SalesPerson, 
CustomerName(Select CustomerName from Customer where Customer.CustomerId = NewInvoice_1.CustomerName) AS CustomerName, 
OrderNumber,  GrandTotal,

(SELECT SUM(PaymentAmount) FROM Payment_Receipt WHERE Payment_Receipt.InvoiceNumber=NewInvoice_1.InvoiceNumber) AS AmountPaid,

GrandTotal - iif(AmountPaid is null, 0, AmountPaid) AS AmountDue
FROM NewInvoice_1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add new column to the table

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD COLUMN Status TEXT
```

Then use [SWITCH](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/switch-function-HA001228918.aspx) function to compare values and update Status column

```
UPDATE yourTable 
SET Status = SWITCH(
                    AmountDue = GrandTotal, 'NOT PAID',
                    AmountDue < GrandTotal, 'PARTIALLY PAID',
                    AmountDue = 0 , 'PAID'
                   );
```

Comment: Is `text` truly the best data type for such short values?

Comment: Hi @mhasan Thanks for answering, the above table is query table. How can I add this code in Query ? . I updated my question please verify it.